# JSON decode to PHP not working

Tags: php, json, object

I try to put a JSON Object into a PHP Variable, it is not working. When I `var_dump` it, it says `NULL`.

PHP:

```
<?php
$json   = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/ajax/stat/1/profile_body/sta1/drantifat'));
$data   = json_decode($json, false);

$money = $data->tplc->stats;   // -> What do i have to do to reach the id:GTA Online Cash and use the val: $33.9K ?
?>
```

JSON file example: (it changes over time)

```
{"cid":0,"ttl":"Grand Theft Auto V",
"ishs":false,"issa":false,"istc":false,"htl":true,"tlc":"text",
"tlt":"View Stats","tlh":"/member/drantifat/games/gtav/career/overview",
"iso":false,"cmng":false,"order":0,"uid":0,"ttc":0,
"tplc":"{\"game\":\"GTAV\",\"stats\":[{\"id\":\"Game Progress\",\"val\":\"58.77%\"},
{\"id\":\"Missions Passed\",\"val\":\"55\"},{\"id\":\"Playing Time\",\"val\":\"29:00:33\"},
{\"id\":\"GTA Online RP\",\"val\":\"2.4M\"},{\"id\":\"GTA Online Rank\",\"val\":\"128\"},
{\"id\":\"GTA Online Cash\",\"val\":\"$33.9K\"},
{\"id\":\"GTA Online Playing Time\",\"val\":\"529:44:12\"}],
\"url\":\"/member/drantifat/games/gtav/career/overview\"}","isa":false,"cnt":""}
```

Could anyone also help me with what I've mentioned in the PHP file?

Comment: As you can see in the output, `$data->tplc` is another **string** containing JSON.

Comment: Wish I could test this, that URL returns no data for me

Comment: @wavemode its true, i see that now. Im glad you've said it, as i see you have to be logged into Rockstar. I think my 'webhost' isnt logged into Rockstar lets say that. Otherwise it would work? I'll test it on localhost and will response once again.

Answer (score 1):

`tplc` isn't a JSON object, it's a string that is itself JSON.

```
<?php
$json = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/ajax/stat/1/profile_body/sta1/drantifat'));
$data = json_decode($json, false);
$tplc = json_decode($data->tplc);
$money = $tplc->stats;
?>
```

To get the money value specifically:

```
<?php
$json = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/ajax/stat/1/profile_body/sta1/drantifat'));
$data = json_decode($json, false);
$tplc = json_decode($data->tplc);
$stats = $tplc->stats;
foreach ($tplc->stats as $stat) {
    if ($stat->id == 'GTA Online Cash') {
        $money = $stat->val;
        break;
    }
}
echo $money;
?>
```

Comment: Still `NULL` ? Maybe i have to access an object with a value first. How do i access the money part, because as i see it is an array. It has multiple 'items' lets say.

Comment: @Αράπης Make sure the URL is actually returning data (e.g. `echo $json;`). For me it just returns an empty string. I added how to access the money value specifically.